# python linear chart with min max and Avg

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I wonder how in Python I can create a line graph that shows the maximum, minimum and the average for a given epoch. I don't know much about this language and how to make one x have 3 y values. I would like to create something like:

[image]

I tried to do it this way
the first column is the epoch, the second adaptation.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

data = df.groupby(["epoch"],as_index=False).agg({'adaptation':{np.max, np.min, np.mean}})
data.reset_index(inplace=True)

ax = data.plot(x='epoch', y='adaptation', c='white')
plt.fill_between(x='epoch', y1='Low Value', y2='High Value', data=data)

plt.show()
```

but it doesn't work.
My Data data.csv:

```
epoch,adaptation
0,11538314
0,0
0,11983512
0,12897261
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,8931799
0,12849768
0,11138070
0,0
0,12522918
0,0
0,11309842
1,0
1,0
1,9626928
1,11579548
1,10486644
1,11085142
1,8866995
1,12704713
1,0
1,0
1,0
1,11435553
1,0
1,11833946
1,8031767
1,7454479
1,0
1,0
1,13015695
1,10756224
1,0
1,12295841
1,0
1,12224471
2,0
2,7088825
2,12784235
2,12823529
2,10266321
2,0
2,0
2,12671855
2,7107685
3,0
3,9771319
3,13072968
3,8451687
3,9556870
3,0
3,8557863
4,12200947
4,11080982
4,10201426
4,12249544
4,11955293
4,11910369
4,12048186
4,10688168
4,0
4,9276116
```

and so on, each epoch has the same number of records with adaptation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [named aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) to create columns for `min`, `max`, and `mean` for each epoch. You can then plot the `mean` (average) with `data.plot`, and use `plt.fill_between` to fill the area between `min` and `max` values.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

data = df.groupby(["epoch"],as_index=False).agg(
    min=pd.NamedAgg(column="adaptation", aggfunc="min"),
    max=pd.NamedAgg(column="adaptation", aggfunc="max"),
    mean=pd.NamedAgg(column="adaptation", aggfunc=np.mean))
data.reset_index(inplace=True)


ax = data.plot(x='epoch', y='mean', c='brown')
ax.fill_between(x='epoch', y1='min', y2='max', data=data,
                color=mpl.colors.to_rgba('brown', 0.15))
plt.show()
```

For the data that you have provided, the line graph will be completely filled, because your `min` value is 0 for every epoch, and your `max` value is similar in every epoch. The graph for your data will look like this:

[image: Plot of the provided data]

This method of visualization will make more sense if your `min` and `max` values for every epoch are closer to the `mean` value, and follow its trend, like in the image below that was made with custom data:

[image: Plot of more meaningful data]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I just wanted to ask, I noticed that if the y values are too big it gets something like this: 
`raise TypeError(f"Could not convert {x} to numeric") from err
TypeError: Could not convert adaptationadaptationadaptation.... to numeric`
can it be avoided somehow fixed?